# Custom deployment slots in Azure cloud service(classic)

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Azure classic cloud services have two deployment slots by default: productiona nd staging.
Is there a way to create a custom deployment slots, says dev and tests.

I know azure app services and web services have support for above.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible and on top of that cloud services are really old, I'd suggest going some other routes.